# SQL Join even if there's a mismatch

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables structured like so:

Table A

```
[ID_A] [name]
1      hello
2      world
```

Table B

```
[ID_B] [name]
1      foo
2      bar
3      booboo
```

Table C

```
[ID_C] [ID_A] [ID_B]
1      1      1
2      1      2
3      2      2
```

What i want to have is: for each A.name return a row with 0 or 1 based on the existance of a link between itself and all of the entries in B

Result:

```
[A.ID] [B.ID] [res]
1      1      1
1      2      1
1      3      0
2      1      0
2      2      1
2      3      0
```

I tried with normal joins, full outer joins (in my mind they worked perfectly), but i can't manage to do it, because i can't perform a join if there is no row to join on

Comment: cross join. . . . . . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CROSS JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.id_a, 
       B.id_b, 
       Coalesce(res, 0)  as res
FROM   tablea A 
       CROSS JOIN tableb B 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id_a,id_b,1 AS res 
                  FROM   tablec) C 
              ON A.id_a = C.id_a
                 AND B.id_b = C.id_b
```

Comment: I completely forgot cross join existed. Thank you so much, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tablea table ( ID_A int, name varchar(12) )
declare @tableb table ( ID_B int, name varchar(12) )
declare @tablec table ( ID_C int, ID_A int, ID_B int )

insert @tablea values (1, 'hello'), (2, 'world')
insert @tableb values (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'booboo')
insert @tablec values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 2)

select 
    ID_A as [A.ID],
    ID_B as [B.ID],
    (select count(*) from @tablec c where a.ID_A = c.ID_A and b.ID_B = c.ID_B) [res]
from @tablea A, @tableb B
order by a.ID_A, b.ID_B
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a left-join, but start with the table you want ALL possible entries to.  Do not truly JOIN to the per-user account so it will force the Cartesian result per person to the name lookup table.  Finally the left-join to identify IF it exists or not.

```
select
      a.name as NameFromA,
      a.id_a,
      b.name as NameFromB,
      b.id_b,
      case when c.id_c IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as ExistsInTableC
   from
      TableA a
         JOIN TableB b   (no actual JOIN ON clause)
            LEFT JOIN TableC c
               on a.id_a = c.id_a
              AND b.id_b = c.id_b
```